# open source e commerce solution

Tags: layout, open-source, e-commerce

I tested the OpenCart but I noticed that is quite problematic to change the layout.

I need to use a specific layout that i have done, so, my question is: *what is the ecommerce open source solution that permit a more easy adaptivity of the layout?*

as you can imagine is complicated test all e commerce solutions...

thanks

Comment: opencart is simply and easy to use by end client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fantastic CMS Umbraco is open source and there's a super easy to use and style low budget e-commerce called [Tea Commerce](http://www.teacommerce.dk/) to it.

It's based on ajax and has a very simple JavaScript library which makes it both fun and easy to setup. You can do any design with Tea Commerce.

/Rune

Comment: I am not interested in asp.net. thanks